# Mouseover event in column of ngx-datatable

Tags: angular, typescript, datatable, mouseevent, ngx-datatable

I need to change one of the column of ngx data-table on mouseover i.e mainly to show the buttons when user hovers a row and show label when row is not hovered.
I am using: https://swimlane.github.io/ngx-datatable/ data table.

Below is the code:

Html:

```
    <ngx-datatable-column prop="created">
  <ng-template ngx-datatable-header-template>
    Created 

  </ng-template>
  <div (mouseover)="getMouseOver()" (mouseleave)="getMouseLeave()">
    <ng-template ngx-datatable-cell-template let-row="row" let-column="column" let-value="value" ngIf="isHoverButtonVisible">
      {{value|timeSince}}
    </ng-template>

    <ng-template ngx-datatable-cell-template let-row="row" let-column="column" let-value="value" ngIf="!isHoverButtonVisible">
     Hello
    </ng-template>
  </div>

</ngx-datatable-column>
```

Ts:

mouseover and mouseleave are not getting control.

```
  getMouseOver() {
   this.isHoverButtonVisible = true;
  }

  getMouseLeave() {
    this.isHoverButtonVisible = false;
  }
```

Comment: try using @HostListener in ur .ts file